# how to get product specific attribute codes & values using raw sql query?

Tags: product-attribute, sql

The following query will give product all attribute codes & values.but I want specific attributes.and i want to store that result into one table.the table format like flat catalog product table.

**Note:question is updated.**

```
$query = "SELECT    ce.sku,          
       ea.attribute_code,
       CASE ea.backend_type
          WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
          WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
          WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
          WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
          WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
          ELSE ea.backend_type
       END AS value
   FROM (select sku ,entity_type_id,entity_id from catalog_product_entity where type_id='simple' limit $limit,$offset ) AS ce
   LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
       ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar
       ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id
       AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id
       AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
       ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id
       AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id
       AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text
       ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id
       AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id
       AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
       ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id
       AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id
       AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime
       ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id
       AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id
       AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'";
```

Comment: why do you need it from a query? Can't you just use collections?

Comment: product collection above 4lakh.so i think through raw sql query i can get some performance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If we know the end result helping you might be easier

Comment: I want to store into one table like flat catalog table.but in my table i need all atttributes with sku as primary key.

Comment: and i have external system contains same table schema.i need to generate a report by  comparing these two tables data through cron.

Comment: `fetchAll` for 4 lac is not a good idea either. You should set up some cron job to do this incrementally so that your server doesn't suffer when this query is executed. Also, check for the out of memory errors too.

Comment: yes.correct.i will use cronjob with batch jobs.

Answer (score 4):

For Magento version 2.2, where a new redirection has been added in their EAV model, below query is working for my project. There the `entity_type_id` needed to be retrieved from `catalog_product_entity`.

```
SELECT    ce.sku,           
        ea.attribute_code,
        CASE ea.backend_type
           WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
           WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
           WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
           WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
           WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
           ELSE ea.backend_type
        END AS value
    FROM (select cpe.sku, eas.entity_type_id, cpe.entity_id 
                FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe, eav_attribute_set AS eas
                WHERE cpe.attribute_set_id=eas.attribute_set_id) AS ce
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
        ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id
        AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id
        AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id
        AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id
        AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id
        AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime';
```

Comment: This is incorrect, entity_type_id does not exist in catalog_product_entity.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing more harm than good by avoiding the proper way of handling this. I would like to be sure that people know this is very much unacceptable if developing for a client or on a live production site.

The proper method would be to obtain the product collection, where you can apply any required filtering methods to reduce the collection to whatever is needed.  Once you have your collection, then use the Magento Framework `walk()` method defined in the `core/resource_iterator` model class: `./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Iterator.php`.

An example is fairly well illustrated within `magento/app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/NotifyStock.php`:

```
 // ...
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = $product->getCollection();
        Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock')->addLowStockFilter($collection, array(
            'qty',
            'notify_stock_qty',
            'low_stock_date',
            'use_config' => 'use_config_notify_stock_qty'
        ));
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name', true)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',
                array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds())
            )
            ->setOrder('low_stock_date');
         
        /*
        using resource iterator to load the data one by one instead of loading all at the same time. loading all data at the same time can cause big memory allocation.
        */
        Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
            $collection->getSelect(),
            array(array($this, 'addNotifyItemXmlCallback')),
            array('rssObj'=> $rssObj, 'product'=>$product, 'globalQty' => $globalNotifyStockQty)
        );
```

---

I also think you may be unaware that EAV attribute table relations within Magento are not handled with `left join`, instead, they are actually done with `union`

Answer (score -1):

Following code is working fine.

```
 <?php
    include ('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = "SELECT    ce.sku,           
            ea.attribute_code,
            CASE ea.backend_type
               WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
               WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
               WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
               WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
               WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
               ELSE ea.backend_type
            END AS value
        FROM (select sku ,entity_type_id,entity_id from catalog_product_entity limit 100) AS ce
        LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
            ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
        LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar
            ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id
            AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id
            AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
        LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
            ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id
            AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id
            AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
        LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text
            ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id
            AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id
            AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
        LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
            ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id
            AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id
            AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
        LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime
            ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id
            AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id
            AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'";
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

Comment: This is incorrect, entity_type_id does not exist in catalog_product_entity.